# How do I access elements of an array in a property in Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

The following code works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Menu_dropdown from "./component/menu_dropdown";

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      races: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(races => {this.setState({ races : races})});
  }


  render(){
    const { races } = this.state;
    console.log(races['results']);
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Menu_dropdown races = {races}/>
      </header>
    </div>
    );
  }
  
}

export default App;
```

console will output an array of races. However,it gives me "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when I change to this

```
console.log(races['results'][0]);
```

why is results not an array? You can view source json here:
https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races/

Comment: How does `races` look like?

Comment: I'm surprised `console.log(races['results']);` gives you an output as on the first render `races.results` will be undefined too.

Comment: Is render waiting for did mount? If not then [this is a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: races is {}, after get response from the api, it returns a javascript object with 2 properties: counts and results.

Comment: simply change `console.log(races['results']);` to `console.log(races['results'][0]);` in context you will get the not working code

Comment: Got it, i just reread the question. Working on the solution :))

Comment: I do not think render is waiting for did  mount, because console can output the result of races. I can also access `races[count]` which is 9, and `races[results]` which gives me an array. But if I go `races[results][0]`, I get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When state is first initialized to `{ races: {}}`, `races.results` will be undefined and you can't get any elements from undefined.

Simply change the constructor to:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      races: {results: []}
    }
  }
```

This way the component can render an empty array while loading and the fetch results when the fetch call is resolved.